# How to get page visitor percentage in total user

Tags: javascript, css, jsp

i want to set a query which show percentage of visitors out of toal register useser in jsp how i can do it in jsp page.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hard to help without seeing your code. Please post up the HEAD code from your page(s).

Comment: From what you've posted it looks as if it should all be fine :/

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some code. Thanks.

If you have copied the entire content of your index.html into some other files, then they should be in the very same directory, otherwise the browser cannot find your css file.

Comment: - Make sure you insert the reference to the main.css in each html file accordingly.
 - You are working with IDs to identify the different types of style, obviously. Make sure each html node gets an id attribute in order to give it a style.

Comment: You are using the attribute id as well as class to identify html nodes. You should use dots and hashes in your main.css to provide a style for these nodes. Furthermore, make sure your reference to the main.css is always correct.

Comment: Each html file needs its own head, obviously. For the css issue, please take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp

Comment: i copy pase all code of index.html to other html file so all have same link any if index.html can access to her design id or classes then other why not?

Comment: 1) Each html file needs this piece of html in the head section:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">

2) Make sure your css is relating to the correct html nodes.

Comment: as you mention <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css"> 2) i just provide link as <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css"> ) but you also give 2 but i not mention page number may be it is a mistake thanx

Comment: a single css file can be used in multiple html files, that is not the point I guess.

Please provide your css file. Thx :)